# JSF2 actionListener not called (Tomcat 7)

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7, el

My listener never gets called?

I'm using Tomcat 7(EL 2.2 compliant) and JSF 2.2.

Here is a snippet of the xhtml:

```html
<h:form>Account Code:
    <h:inputText id="accountcode" value="#{report.accountCode}" />
        <br />
        e-mail:
    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{report.email}" />
    <br />
    <h:commandButton value="Go">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{report.runReportAjax}" render="output" />
    </h:commandButton>
    <h:inputText id="output" value="#{report.message}" />
</h:form>
```

And here is the listener:

```
public void runReportAjax(final AjaxBehaviorEvent e) throws AbortProcessingException {
    message = "Reports are being generated...";
}
```

My getter & setter get called as expected. Tomcat 7 is supposed to be EL2.2 compliant but even so I copied el-api-2.2.jar & el-impl-2.2.jar into tomcat's lib folder as well as the project lib folder.

I tried different variations of these but still the same result. I finally restored tomcat back to it's original state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At this line try `<f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{report.runReportAjax}" render="output" />`